# Is there a way to update a userform to update in the listbox

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you in advance.

I have a UserForm1 that contains ListBox1. The ListBox1 shows the range of data from the excel sheet.

If I click on data from ListBox1, it pops up Userform2 with the corresponding data.

In essence, if the user wants to edit the data in ListBox1, they would double click on the data which pops up as UserForm2, and CommandButton1 as a saving function. This should then be displayed in the ListBox1 with the changes.

The issue I have is that if I edit the data in UserForm2 and click on the CommandButton1, it does not reflect in my ListBox1 and it gives me the error code, "Run-time error'70': Could not set the Column Property. Permission Denied.

The code I have for the ListBox1 is as follows:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
UserForm2.TextBox9.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(0)
UserForm2.TextBox1.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(1)
UserForm2.TextBox2.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(2)
UserForm2.TextBox3.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(3)
UserForm2.TextBox4.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(4)
UserForm2.TextBox5.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(5)
UserForm2.TextBox6.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(6)
UserForm2.TextBox7.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(7)
UserForm2.TextBox8.Text = Me.ListBox1.Column(8)
UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

The code I have for CommandButton1 is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(0) = Me.TextBox9.Text
UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(1) = Me.TextBox1.Text
UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(2) = Me.TextBox2.Text
UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(3) = Me.TextBox3.Text
UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(4) = Me.TextBox4.Text
UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(5) = Me.TextBox5.Text
UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(6) = Me.TextBox6.Text
UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(7) = Me.TextBox7.Text
UserForm1.ListBox1.Column(8) = Me.TextBox8.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: have u tried editing the modifiers to your listbox?

Comment: You cannot change a Listbox List values when you have the Listbox RowSource set to a range.  You can load the ranges values into the listbox like this `ListBox.List = Range.Value` and then modify the ListBox.List values.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
UserForm2.TextBox1.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(0)
UserForm2.TextBox2.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(1)
UserForm2.TextBox3.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(2)
UserForm2.Show

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
For i = 1 To 3
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem Cells(i, 1).Value
Next
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm1.ListBox1.List(0) = Me.TextBox1.Value
UserForm1.ListBox1.List(1) = Me.TextBox2.Value
UserForm1.ListBox1.List(2) = Me.TextBox3.Value

End Sub
```

[image]